# mysql query to get list including duplicates from array

Tags: mysql, node.js, duplicates

I am trying to run a list of 12 numbers into a mysql query. The list contains duplicates that get ignored in the results of the query, changing the overall length of the list. I'm still learning mysql's potential so apologies if I am missing something basic. this code is being applied to a bot that allows a trading card game to be played via discord.

I have tried multiple different results people have put on here and nothing has worked how I wanted it to. From Union all to joins, nothing seems to help. Granted, I haven't seen someone be in quite the same position I am.

masterlist is a table in the same database that is a list of 52 rows.

array is an array of 12 numbers that can be found in the ID field of the masterlist. This array originates from a table made by the two players in an earlier step of the card game.

type is a value that is found corresponding to the ID. Each type is shared across multiple ID's.

```
con.query(`SELECT a.id, a.type FROM masterlist a,
        (SELECT id, type 
        FROM masterlist
        WHERE id in (${array.join(", ")})
        GROUP by id, type
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) b
        WHERE  a.id = b.id
        AND a.type = b.type`
```

This returns an empty array.

The problem is that any duplicate numbers in the array are ignored. The results of this query is going to have an id matching it in a separate list (type[0] will correspond to id[0]. One of the results is going to be selected at random based on the type. If a duplicate is ignored, that lessens the chances that id is selected at random. I hope this makes sense. This is for a discord bot that allows players to play a trading card game with each other so keeping the chances as fair as possible is important.

I want the result of listing all 12 values (types), duplicates included in a single array after the query or queries are done (no grouping of duplicate values). Efficiency isn't really a concern, as the masterlist will not be thousands of entries long. At this point, I just want something functional, even if it requires a couple different queries to accomplish it.

EDIT:
Here is what prints to console. https://i.gyazo.com/b843d8831d7801f14f34edc94a2a1831.png 
First line is the array of numbers as taken from the table where the numbers were originally stored after being input by the two players in the game. The second line is those same numbers sorted in ascending order. The result from the query above is the third line, just an empty array.

The expected result should be something like this, EXCEPT it should have 12 values not 11. https://i.gyazo.com/fffd26c1628fbb2374070f7154c28b7b.png
The original set of values in "array" had 12 numbers, with the value 7 having a duplicate. This array of values was printed from this https://i.gyazo.com/151ebf67c0f2871661bd819e3c8865f9.png passing the array into the query without any subqueries or joins or unions. I understand this query, as written, only lists unique values in results if the id was different. I want the list of numbers passed into a query or queries to retrieve all 12 types that associate with it, listed in the same order as the sorted array input above.

For example the original array was this:

```
[ '1', '4', '5', '7', '7', '8', '12', '17', '24', '38', '45', '48' ]
```

This is what I expect the output to be:

```
[ 'greenfist',
  'greenfist',
  'greenfist',
  'greenfist',
  **'greenfist',**
  'greenfist',
  'greenfist',
  'flamefist',
  'shield',
  'magicshield',
  'helix',
  'helix' ]
```

The value with **'s is the duplicate of 7 from array that is ignored in the query that has no union, joins or subqueries used. The input COULD have duplicates, triplicates, quadruplicates, etc as well, so it would need the ability to list all copies.

EDIT2: This is the table for "masterlist". https://i.gyazo.com/41571f2da48d11373f884d23b4e3e92d.png
Note: I changed Coreid to "id" in the post so far just to simplify things. When I run the code, I have the correct variables placed. The name for the ID's listed are "cores" in the card game, so I felt that was superfluous. I don't need the effect1, faction1, effect2 or faction2 info from this query. I just need the coreid and type.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add sample input and expected output and what is the value of **array** in above query ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Added what I think you're looking for in edit section.

Comment: Could you please provide the data in **masterlist** table ? you make so complicated question

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Added a screenshot for the entire table in EDIT2. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: It is better to handle such scenarios in code instead of doing all this mess in query, As you are getting value from table so MySQL always return the unique result as per your requirement, In code what you have to do is just map each type against each Id.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I hadn't considered mapping, just because I'm not terribly familiar with it. I've heard of it, but just haven't used it yet. I'm learning as I make this project. So something like this maybe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array

So pulling everything from masterlist and mapping it for reference later by id? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: So if you have 7 as duplicate then put twice value of type (**greenfist**)